# How do I remove the margin when drawing a rectangle inside a panel in a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Firstly, for context, I'm a beginner in C# and I'm playing around with forms.

I have attempted to draw a rectangle to a panel ("myPanel") on a form ("Form1") but there is a margin or some sort of padding which I cannot remove.

I have set the "padding" and "margin" properties of "myPanel" to 0 with no success.

The code is:

```
namespace Forms___Playing_with_Graphics
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            // rectangle, slightly smaller than size of panel
            int topLeftx = myPanel.Location.X;
            int topLefty = myPanel.Location.Y;
            int width = myPanel.Size.Width - 5;
            int height = myPanel.Size.Height - 5;

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(topLeftx, topLefty, width, height);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 5F);

            g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
        }
    }
}
```

A screenshot of the result:

[image: Panel with mysterious padding]

How do I remove this padding between the rectangle and the inside left and top edges?  My naive expectation was for the rectangle to start in the very top-left corner.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The inside of the panel has its own coordinates, so topLeftx = 0, topLefty = 0.

Comment: Don't use `myPanel.Location`, the drawing should be inside `myPanel.ClientRectangle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top left corner has coordinates x = 0, y = 0. But you should also keep in mind width of rectangle border. If you want rectangle border to fit exactly to the panel which contains it, then you should step inside half of border width:

```
private void myPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float borderWidth = 5f;
    float topLeftx = borderWidth / 2;
    float topLefty = borderWidth / 2;
    float width = panel2.ClientSize.Width - borderWidth;
    float height = panel2.ClientSize.Height - borderWidth;

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, borderWidth);
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, topLeftx, topLefty, width, height);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `plotWindow.ClientSize`

Comment: @LarsTech that's another control, not related to `myPanel`

Comment: Then I assume the OP wants `myPanel.ClientSize`.  It's not clear where plotWindow is coming into play.

Comment: @LarsTech OP clearly stated that he wants left and top edges to fit: '*How do I remove this padding between the rectangle and the inside left and top edges?*'. So it's up to OP to decide what should be height and width here

Comment: I'm going with plotWindow is supposed to be myPanel.  Call it a typo on the OP's part.

Comment: @Paul updated as well. You should subtract  border width from both height and width of panel client size (height/2 twice)